# Javascript error. Page reloading

Tags: javascript

I wrote an javascript for my html page and its working fine except the fact that its reloading on every click.I dont know why. I have added `return false` but it still reloading. Please tell me the reason.

```
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {

    document.getElementById('edit' + i).addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        document.getElementById(i + "1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(i + "2").style.display = "table-row";
        return false;
      }
    }(i)));
    document.getElementById('cancel' + i).addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        document.getElementById(i + "2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(i + "1").style.display = "table-row";
        return false;
      }
    }(i)));
    document.getElementById('link' + i).addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
      return function() {
        if (document.getElementById("option" + i).style.display == "none") {
          document.getElementById("option" + i).style.display = "table-row";
          return false;
        } else {
          document.getElementById("option" + i).style.display = "none";
          return false;
        }
      }
    }(i)));
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: What makes you think we can solve it without html ?

Comment: did you try `.preventDefault()`?

Comment: is the click inside a form?

Comment: @Kinnza Yes,It is inside the form

Comment: Change the button type from "submit" to "button", that should solve it.
You can also bind an event to the form submit action and return false

Comment: @RoyiNamir I have 10 fields like info1,info2,.....info9 cancel1,cancel2.....cancel9

Comment: @Kinnza Nice catch buddy..Got my answer..Thanx.. :)